# How to do a word search on a large text database

Tags: android, database, search, text

I have a large database in my app. One column is made of text strings that are about a sentence to a paragraph long. I would like to make this column searchable by word(s) that the user inputs.

How would I make a quick search? I've heard of making an index but I don't know how to do that for a text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has a mechanism for storing a lot of text in a database, it's called [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) (short for full text search).
Android supports all SQLite commands, so you can easily just use FTS3.

How is explained in the documentation linked above.

Example for creating a table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);  /* FTS3 table */
CREATE TABLE enrondata2(content TEXT);                     /* Ordinary table */
```

Query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';  /* 0.03 seconds */
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata2 WHERE content LIKE '%linux%'; /* 22.5 seconds */
```

Comment: **%linux%** will find linux in a word. Is there a way to get search for words start with 'linux' word.

Comment: @Shubh Omit the first `%`, it's a wildcard. Removing the first will find only words starting with `linux`.